# Cassandra Single node server error: Found system keyspace files, but they couldn't be loaded

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have a single node machine of Cassandra. To stop Cassandra I used `ps-ef|grep cassandra` and killed the process.
Now, when I start cassandra, I get this exception:

> ERROR 16:56:27,030  Fatal exception during initialization
>   org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Found system keyspace files, but they couldn't be loaded!
>       at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:603) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.14.1346.jar:2.1.14.1346]

I can see the keyspaces present in the data folder. As this is a single node machine, I cannot clean the node and pull data from other nodes.
Nodetool won't work as C* is not working.
How to solve?

Comment: Was there any other errors alongside that? I would say if I had to guess check the permissions on the `<cassandra data>/system` directory and make sure the user (`cassandra` by default) has permissions to those files and the parent directory

Comment: I faced this issue long ago. As the replication factor was 1, the data was corrupted and lost. Anyway I was just learning. So, np. The permissions were correct at that time. Anyways,a appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the system keyspace and starting it with its token. - This worked for me.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8330

Comment: Can you edit your answer and provide the relevant details from the Jira ticket?